# Change a table row dynamically using JQuery/Javascrpit

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

So I've made a table using a for loop in java spring and I want to toggle parts of it on and off when a button is clicked so a super simplified version looks something like this

```
<jsp:attribute name= "scripts">
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function togglet(){
            $('.wantTotoggleThis').toggle();
            $('.iWantToReplaceItWithThis').toggle();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.iWantToReplaceItWithThis').hide();
        })
    </script>
</jsp:attribute>
<table>
<tbody>
    <c:foreach var = "whatever" items = "$list">
    <td class = "wantTotoggleThis"> Hello </td>
    <td class = "iWantToReplaceItWithThis"> Replaced </td>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle()" >
</tbody>
</table>
```

The way I toggle them right now is I just use a toggle function, but the draw back to that is that every single in the entry in the table gets toggled. I only want to be able to toggle the row where I clicked the button on.

Comment: For what purpose did you tag this with `java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the element into `onclick` so you can traverse from that element

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)" >
```

JS

```
function togglet(el){
    $(el).siblings('.wantTotoggleThis, .iWantToReplaceItWithThis').toggle();            
 }
```

Note that using `onclick` is an outdated practice and it is better to use modern unobtrusive event listeners.

Also going to run into funky table layouts as a result of toggling individual cells. Changing `visibility` might be a better approach

Comment: Works! Thank you, and yea changing visibility worked out much better!

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way of doing this if anyone else is interested by using a function

```
function toggleSomething(element){
  var row = $(element).closest.('tr');
  row.find('.iwantTotoggleThis').toggle();
  row.find('.iWantToReplaceItWithThis').toggle();
 }
```